# bloggers <data:post.url/> doesn't work in jscript

Tags: javascript, blogger

I have the problem with Blogger in defining data:post.url in variable for further output, for instance if I use data:blog.url it works perfectly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var posturl="<data:blog.url/>"
</script>
```

giving workable link from this statement:

```
var summary = 
'<a href="'+posturl+'">' '</a>';
div.innerHTML = summary;
```

but with data:post.url i just receive `TEMPLATE ERROR:No dictionary named:'post'in:['blog','skin','view']`

please advise if some one knows the reason, thanks!

Comment: I think this variable is available inside the post includable.

Comment: Thanks! you are right, it took me to days to answer this question before i posted it here, just moved the script to includable area...how simple